# Problems with broken image icon

Tags: javascript, html, image, leaflet

I have a leaflet map running on a server whose popups are automatically filled with images. Some popups contain three images. The problem is that the broken image icon appears on those that contain fewer images. I've already tried to remove them with `alt=""`, but it doesn't work.

Attached is a link to the app/code.

```
function forEachFeatureCC(feature, layer) {
  var popUp =
    "<h2>" + feature.properties.Name + "</h2>" +
    "<img src='" + feature.properties.Bildlink + "'width='300'</img>" +
    "<br>" + "<br>" +
    "<h4>" + feature.properties.Beschreibung +
    "<br>" + "<br>" + 
    "<img src='" + feature.properties.Bildlink_2 + "'width='300'</img>" +
    "<br>" + "<br>" +
    "<img src='" + feature.properties.Bildlink_3 + "' width='300' alt=''</img>" +
    "<br>" + "<br>";
  layer.bindPopup(popUp).update();
}
```

https://wasserwiki.eu/Wasserwiki_App_Mobile

Comment: Nice page. All I can say about the missing images is that things like `feature.properties.Bildlink_2` appear to be NULL. Why? I have no idea, there's nothing in your question that could help me explain this.

Comment: Thanks! The information is deprived from a geojson file, which contains all the image URLs and information for the different points on the map. Not all points on the map contain a value for the feature "Bildlink_2", since unfortunately, I do not have a second or a third picture for it. Therefore the value is NULL, if there is no more picture available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I see, you simply don't want to show the absent images. In that case you can do:

```
function getImageHtml(imagelink)
{
   return "<img src='"+ imagelink + "' width='300'</img>" + "<br>" + "<br>";
}

function forEachFeatureCC(feature, layer) 
{
    var popUp = "<h2>" + feature.properties.Name + "</h2>";
    if (feature.properties.Bildlink) {
        popUp = popUp + getImageHtml(feature.properties.Bildlink);
    }
    if (feature.properties.Bildlink_2) {
        popUp = popUp + getImageHtml(feature.properties.Bildlink_2);
    }
    if (feature.properties.Bildlink_3) {
        popUp = popUp + getImageHtml(feature.properties.Bildlink_3);
    }
    layer.bindPopup(popUp).update();
}
```

I didn't test the code, so some debugging might be needed, but I think the general idea is clear?

Comment: Thanks again. With some debugging I got your code to work. 
But your first post made me think of something else: Since all non-existent images have  "null" as value, I was able to easily solve the problem with CSS.  img[src="null"] {
    display: none;}  Thanks very much!